# Couchdb ssl not listening on port 6984

Tags: https, couchdb

I've been setting up couchdb to run on SSL following the instructions from couch docs. Its pretty straight forward, you make 3 adjustments to local.ini:

```
httpsd = {chttpd, start_link, [https]}
cert_file = absolute/path/to/cert.pem
key_file = absolute/path/to/key.pem
```

I've made the key and certificate with openssl no problem, but whenever I ping port 6984 on the localhost (the port its supposed to run on by default) I just get a non active port:

```
==> curl https://127.0.0.1:6984/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6984: Connection refused
```

I've inspected the port, nothing is running there. I can put a node.js server on the port and it works fine too. I can't find a similar situation to this anywhere. I'm running the mac OSX couchdb application (v 2.1.2). It appears that the ssl server daemon is just straight up not running at all. Everything else in couch is working fine. Maybe I have to tweak the local.ini file to turn the daemon on? No idea really. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Just as a side note, since your SSL certificate is self signed, you need to use `curl` with `-k` option

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will ever be a very popular question but just thought I'd point out that a very popular way to set up SSL with couchdb is to use a proxy like haproxy due to annoyances with ssl and erlang (which couchdb is written in).

That being said, I solved my problem by setting up SSL termination at haproxy that then forwards traffic to couchdb on an internal port. For use on a mac OSX machine the steps were pretty easy.

1) Install haproxy with brew `brew install haproxy`

2) Create a self signed certificate with openssl that haproxy needs for ssl configuration (it's really just a concatenated file of your key and certificate):

```
openssl genrsa -out key.key 1024
openssl req -new -key key.key -out cert.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in cert.csr -signkey key.key -out certificate.crt
cat ./certificate.crt ./key.key | tee combined.pem
```

3) create haproxy configuration file (haproxy.cfg), this is just a pretty naive first implementation, but is a good starting point. Note that "/absolute/path/to/combined.pem" would be changed to wherever the combined.pem file is actually located.

```
global
        maxconn 512
        spread-checks 5

defaults
        mode http
        log global
        monitor-uri /_haproxy_health_check
        option log-health-checks
        option httplog
        balance roundrobin
        option forwardfor
        option redispatch
        retries 4
        option http-server-close
        timeout client 150000
        timeout server 3600000
        timeout connect 500

        stats enable
        stats uri /_haproxy_stats
        # stats auth admin:admin # Uncomment for basic auth

frontend http-in
         # bind *:$HAPROXY_PORT
         bind *:443 ssl crt /absolute/path/to/combined.pem no-tls-tickets ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:!MD5:!aNULL:!DH:!RC4
         #Add these lines beneath bind, still within http-in
         reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
         # Distinguish between secure and insecure requests
         acl secure dst_port eq 8000
         # Mark all cookies as secure if sent over SSL
         rsprep ^Set-Cookie:\ (.*) Set-Cookie:\ \1;\ Secure if secure
         # Add the HSTS header with a 1 year max-age
         rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=31536000 if secure
         # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
         redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
         default_backend couchdbs

backend couchdbs
        option httpchk GET /_up
        http-check disable-on-404
        server couchdb1 127.0.0.1:5984 check inter 5s
```

4) Run couchdb, run haproxy via changing directory to the directory housing the above haproxy.cfg file and running with that configuration: `haproxy -f haproxy.cfg`.

This is a simple point to start from. This set up can handle load balancing of multiple couchdbs, and in production would need a valid certificate from some authority. For anyone interested in, or having difficulty with ssl and couchdb in a mac OSX development environment, this is a decent solution that I found to work quite nicely.

Comment: I was unable to start haproxy, but this part of the doc solved my identical issue: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/config/http.html#https-ssl-tls-options